# Nested iterating through list followed by an eventual deletion

Tags: java, oop, loops, iterator

I'm trying to iterate throuh a list while already looping through it (nested loops). Consider the code below:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // add some values to it

for(int i : list) { // ConcurrentModificationException

   Iterator iterator = list.iterator();

   while(iterator.hasNext()) {

      int n = iterator.next();

      if(n % i == 0) {
         iterator.remove();
      }

   }

}
```

The example above results in a ConcurrentModificationException. The condition to remove an element is, of course, just an example.

I'm sure I'm just missing something; but **how should I construct a loop that achieves the same thing** in Java without throwing an exception?

Comment: Any suggestions to the question's title is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously modifying `list` when you iterate over it causing the execption.
You can use another list to maintain the list of elements to be removed and remove them at the end.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // add some values to it
ArrayList<Integer> del = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // Elements to be deleted

for(int i : list) { // ConcurrentModificationException
   Iterator iterator = list.iterator();
   while(iterator.hasNext()) {    
      int n = iterator.next();
      if(n % i == 0) {
          del.add(n);      
      }
   }
}

list.removeALL(del);
```

Comment: Err ... shouldn't that be `del.add(n)`?

Comment: This is what I am looking for, however, I need to have  the removing of elements performed just after the while loop is done, that is, at the end of each for-cycle..

Comment: @Zar you can do that as well. Just move the `del` list declaration inside the loop and delete after each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Make the outer iteration iterate over a copy of the list.

```
for (int i : new ArrayList<>(list)) {

  Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();

  while (iterator.hasNext()) {

    int n = iterator.next();

    if (n % i == 0) {
      iterator.remove();
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `ConcurrentModificationException` because, while doing `for` loop you are trying to modify the `list`.

I am not sure whether following is elegant solution or not, but something like below may work:

```
       Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();
            int i=1;
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                int n = iterator.next();

                if (n % i == 0) {
                    iterator.remove();
                }
                i++;
            }
```

Comment: The thing is that I need to use the numbers in the list for the comparasion. Hence, a `i=1 ; i++` won't do it since the numbers aren't 1,2,3 etc

Comment: You are getting numbers in list using iterator, then why do you need for loop?

Comment: I'm learning Java, but doesn't an iterator iterate through the item's (list in this case) values? I need to do a loop on each of the list value, which forces me to use a nested loop.

Comment: Does that mean each item in list is another list or what?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove an item from a list that is being iterated. One option is to add the items that you need to another list. Finally you have list with the items you need. Or you can iterate over the clone of your original list.

Answer (score 0):

i do some thing pretty similar to you. hav e alook at this code .

```
out:for(int h=0; h<tempAl.size(); h++) {
                        if(tempAl.get(0).split("\\s")[0].equals("OFF")){
                            tempAl.remove(0);
                            h=-1;
                            continue;
                        }
                        if(tempAl.get(h).split("\\s")[0].equals("ON")){
                            ONTime= tempAl.get(h);
               ///rest fof the code
    }
```

i think you could also change the index after removing element from the arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried, but either use:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
// add some values to it  
for(Iterator<Integer> iterator1 = list.iterator(); iterator1.hasNext();) { 
    int i = iterator1.next();
    for(Iterator<Integer> iterator2 = list.iterator(); iterator2.hasNext();){
        int n = iterator.next();        
        if(n % i == 0) {          
            iterator2.remove();       
        }     
    }  
}
```

or if this still throws the ConcurrentModificationException (I'm not sure what happens if you use 2 iterators backed by the same list), then use:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
// add some values to it  
for(int i : new ArrayList(list)){ // copy list 
    ...
}
```

Comment: The first soulution still thows a ConcurrentModificationException :-(

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` java syntax hides an iterator but as hiding it, it is not possible to call `remove` method on this one.

So I would do:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // add some values to it

int count = 0;
for(Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator();it.hasNext();count++){ //increments count++
   Integer currentInt = it.next();
   if(currentInt % count == 0){
     it.remove();
   }
}
```

You can see that the same feature is achieved without the need of a secondary iterator.

You can't iterate through the same list in the same time.
To sum up, a `modcount` variable is used to detect unexpected change of itself everytime a list is parallely changed or iterated over.
Leading thus to a `ConcurrentModificationException`.
It appears very often with multithreaded environment and developers must be aware of it.

Furthermore, prefer use `for` loop instead `while` loop to iterate over a collection.

Why ?

Because with the `while` way, you let the iterator object still in scope after the loop whereas with `for`, it doesn't. A simple ackward call to `it.next()` would end up with a `NoSuchElementException`.

It is a best practice to keep ;)