# Removing item from list while iterating

Tags: java, list, concurrency, iterator

While iterating through a list, an item can possibly be removed.

```
private void removeMethod(Object remObj){
    Iterator<?> it = list.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Object curObj= it.next();
        if (curObj == remObj) {
            it.remove();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem for me occurs when the above code can take place in another loop, which is actively iterating the original list.

```
private void performChecks(){
    for(Object obj : list){
        //perform series of checks, which could result in removeMethod 
        //being called on a different object in the list, not the current one
    }
}
```

How can I remove an unknown object from a list while traversing it?

**Example**

I have a list of listener objects.  While notifying the listeners of an event, other listeners may no longer be needed.

Comment: Have you tried using an enhanced for loop and the .remove() method?? And a synchronized class?

Comment: Your problem is not clear to me. Any examples ?

Comment: An enchanced for-loop for the removeMethod? That would throw a [ConcurrencyModificationExceptionError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)

Comment: Example added @BoratSagdiyev

Comment: @Mr_Skid_Marks could you add an example so we can produce your issue?

Comment: @KickButtowski I think I may have found a solution, after realzing some better keywords to search - [this is basically what I was trying to do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625038/nested-iterating-through-list-followed-by-an-eventual-deletion)

Comment: @Mr_Skid_Marks it is not clear what you happened and what you want, yet I am happy you found your answer

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, followings would be the possible solutions(might not be most effective but i think is worth a shot):

Under performChecks() use  `for(Object obj : list.toArray())`

Advantage: every time the list is "refreshed" to array it will reflect the changes.
 Therefore, if the item is removed from the list in the separate loop

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing so I'll answer what I think I understand; your question comes to this: how to remove an item from a list while the list is iterated concurrently and items are being removed OR how to avoid [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html).

First, the problem in your code is that you remove the item with your iterator and not by the list. Second, if you're using concurrency, use the [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) and remove the item with

> list.remove()

to provide a good example for the scenario, check [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/05/avoid-concurrentmodificationexception.html)

so this is not good:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

    myList.add("1");
    myList.add("2");
    myList.add("3");
    myList.add("4");
    myList.add("5");

    Iterator<String> it = myList.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        String value = it.next();
        System.out.println("List Value:"+value);
        if(value.equals("3")) myList.remove(value);
    }
```

and this is good:

```
List<String> myList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>();

    myList.add("1");
    myList.add("2");
    myList.add("3");
    myList.add("4");
    myList.add("5");

    Iterator<String> it = myList.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        String value = it.next();
        System.out.println("List Value:"+value);
        if(value.equals("3")){
            myList.remove("4");
            myList.add("6");
            myList.add("7");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("List Size:"+myList.size());
```